# How can I correctly implement backpropagation using categorical cross-entropy as my loss function in just Numpy and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

**Long story short:** How do I fix my backpropagation code, so that weights and bias are being changed effecively by my `evaluate()` function to present predictions closer to the target values rather than odds no better than guessing?

Details below:

I've currently got the backbone of this neural network from scratch which I'm creating using techniques gleaned from Sentdex's *Neural Networks From Scratch* series on YouTube and a *Towards Data Science* article for the backpropagation part specifically. It works by creating a large class called Neural Network which would have several LayerDense objects associated by composition, which would act as each layer within the neural network.
As my inputs to the neural network, I pass in a batch of 8 records from a Pandas DataFrame, each containing 100 values of 0 or 1, depending on their prefered options. As target values, I pass in another DataFrame containing the actual genders of each participant, with 0 being male and 1 being female.
These LayerDense objects would deal with the forward and backward passes of each layer. Prior to implementing the softmax function and backpropagation, this all worked as expected.

My current issue is getting the `evaluate()` function within the program to run as expected & getting the `run()` function to handle this information correctly.
In theory, the evaluate function should return the loss of each neuron and the run function should handle this and run the backward pass through each neuron, adjusting its weights & biases appropiately.
What actually happens is that my final outputs of classification, which are the confidence levels in predictions, with values closer to 0 representing a male gender prediction and values closer to 1 representing a female gender prediction.
Using categorical cross-entropy as my loss function, how would I properly implement backpropagation in this situation? What may I be doing wrong here?

All resource links used to get this far and the whole source code will be linked below.

**Current evaluation code**

```
def evaluate(self):
        #Target values are the y values that we want to be predicting correctly

        #You can calculate the loss of a categorical neural network (basically most NN) by using
        #categorical cross-entropy

        #Using one-hot encoding to calculate the categorical cross-entropy of data (loss)
        #In one-hot encoding, we assign the target class position we want in our array of outputs
        #Then make an array of 0s of the same length as outputs but put a 1 in the target class position
        #This basically simplifies to just the negative natural logarithm of the predicted target value

        #The following code will represent the confidence values in the predictions made by the NN
        #For this to work, if categorical, the number of outputs must equal the number of possible class targets
        #E.g for gender, there's two possible class targets (0 and 1), so two output neurons
        #The string can be changed to the attribute in the table that you shall be predicting

        #A short but ugly way of getting a start to complete this task
        '''
        loss = -np.log(self._network[-1].output[range(len(self._network[-1].output)),target_values.loc[:,"gender"]])
        average_loss = np.mean(loss)
        '''

        #A nicer way to accomplish the same thing
        samples = len(self._network[-1].output)
        #Clip the values so we don't get any infinity errors if a confidence level happens to be spot on
        y_pred_clipped = np.clip(self._network[-1].output, 1e-7, 1-1e-7)

        #If one-hot encoding has not been passed in
        if len(self._target_values.shape) == 1:
            #Selecting the largest confidences based on their position
            correct_confidences = y_pred_clipped[range(samples),self._target_values[:samples]]
        elif len(self._target_values.shape) == 2:
            #One-hot encoding has been used in this scenario
            correct_confidences = np.sum(y_pred_clipped*self._target_values[:samples], axis=1)

        #Calculate the loss and return
        loss = -np.log(correct_confidences)
        return loss, correct_confidences
```

**Current run() code**

```
def run(self, **kwargs):
        epochs = kwargs['epochs']
        #Start by putting initial inputs into the input layer and generating the network
        self._network[0].forward(self._inputs)
        for i in range(len(self._network)-1):
            #Using the previous layer's outputs as the next layer's inputs
            self._network[i+1].forward(self._network[i].output)

        for i in range(epochs):
            #Forward pass
            self._network[0].forward_pass(self._inputs)
            for i in range(len(self._network)-1):
                output = self._network[i+1].forward_pass(self._network[i].output)

            #Generates the values for loss function, used for training in multiple passes
            #Backbone of backpropagation
            loss = neural.evaluate()

            #Backward pass
            #Somehow find a way to derive the evalaute function on predicted values and target values
            error, confidences = [np.e**-x for x in loss]
            confidences = [np.e**-x for x in confidences]
            error = confidences

            for i in range(len(self._network)-1,-1):
                error = self._network[i-1].backward(error, self._learning_rate)
                print('Epoch %d/%d' % (i+1, epochs))

        #Start by putting initial inputs into the input layer
        self._network[0].forward(self._testing_data)
        for i in range(len(self._network)-1):
            #Using the previous layer's outputs as the next layer's inputs
            self._network[i+1].forward(self._network[i].output)
        print("The network's testing outputs were:", self._network[-1].output)
```

**Backward pass code which runs for each layer**

```
    def backward(self, output_error, learning_rate):
        #The error of this layer's inputs is equal to its output error multipled by the 
        #transposed weights of the layer
        input_error = np.dot(output_error, self.weights.T)
        #The error of the weights in this layer is equal to the transposed matrix of inputs fed into the layer
        #multipled by the error of the output from this layer
        weights_error = np.dot(self.inputs.T, output_error)
        # dBias = output_error

        # update parameters
        self.weights -= learning_rate * weights_error
        self.biases -= learning_rate * output_error
        return input_error
```

**Aforementioned softmax function within forward() function of LayerDense**

```
elif self._activation_function.lower() == 'softmax':
                    #Exponentiate (e to the power of x) values and subtract largest value of layer to prevent overflow
                    #Afterwards, normalise (put as relative fractions) the output values
                    #In theory, to get the max value out of each batch, axis should be set to 1 and keepdims should be True
                    neuron_output = np.exp(neuron_output - np.max(layer_output,axis=0)) / np.sum(np.exp(layer_output),axis=0)
```

Mentioned SentDex tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcjD5BAw2DxE6OF2tius3V3

Mentioned TDS article: https://towardsdatascience.com/math-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-d6da9f29ce65

Source code: https://github.com/NewDeveloper911/Python-Collection/blob/master/neural%20network/nn

Comment: Please **clarify exactly* what the issue is with your existing implementation (do not do it in the comments, edit & update your post accordingly).

Comment: @desertnaut The edit has been made. Hopefully, the summary at the top helps.